# Subreport not showing all records when pass datasource as field

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Subreport not showing all records.

Here is my class:

```
Class ReportObject{

    private List <Student> students;
}
```

Subreport Data source expression is : `$F{students}`

```xml
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{students}]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

In subreport jrxml I'm using ***`Student`*** class members.
When run application it's showing first record only, but students list has 8 records.

Comment: it's not a sql, i'm preparing students list object in java

Comment: @RaviKumar You should post your `jrxml` file (at least the snippet with `$F{students}` declaration)

Comment: did you put your <![CDATA[$F{students}]]> in a header?

Comment: ya It's there in Group header-1

Comment: This is wrong what I am thinking. You should put in a Detail Section in the jrxml.

Comment: <subreport isUsingCache="true">
     <reportElement key="recoveryCost_subreport" positionType="Float" x="-13" y="150" width="756" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
     <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{students}]]></dataSourceExpression>
     <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{reportDirectory}.getCanonicalPath() + java.io.File.separator + "studentDetails.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>

Comment: Could you please extend your sub report in the master report and return to us what has happened?

Comment: I'm new to jasper...how to extend sub report

Comment: ok just open your general report which your sub report is in and on the Designer extend the size of your sub report.

Comment: You have to put your fields inside the Detail Band

Comment: Thanks, I've placed in detail band also and extended size also..still same problem..

Comment: have you previewed your sub report individually? rather than implementing in the general report...

Comment: Thanks all for spending your valuable time with me..finally it's working. problem is i have placed sub list items in Title section. Just i have moved to details section

Comment: @Ravi Since you found the answer to your question, you can now answer it yourself and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution,
Initially i have designed sub report in title band.
I have moved this subreport from title band to details section and now working fine